# Put a view on top when camera is open in android

Tags: android

I want an image on top of the cameraview. i.e I want to put an image when the camera is running on top of it.
Can anyone provide me a working code.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I could only open the camera. Do you have a working code for that. please help.

Comment: I cant help without seeing the code I can only tell the mods in your code as my employer dont allow me to help any further so post your related xml and code

Comment: Thanks ingsaurabh . I will try it out and if any problem i will come for help.

Answer (score 0):

Override SurfaceView called CameraPreview.

When your activities resumes tell your View to:

Start the Camera -

```
mCamera = Camera.open()
```

Get the SurfaceHolder for your View -

```
mHolder = getHolder()
```

Set the Holder type -

```
mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)
```

Add a SurfaceHolder.Callback to your holder -

```
mHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() { ... }
```

Implement surfaceCreated in your Callback to setup the camera preview -

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder) (try + catch)
```

Implement surfaceChanged in your Callback to setup & start camera preview -

```
mCamera.setParameters(...) & mCamera.startPreview()
```

Implement surfaceDestroyed in your Callback to stop the camera preview -

```
mCamera.stopPreview()
```

When your activity pauses:

Release the Camera

```
 (mCamera.release())
```

Use your new CameraPreview View in xml or add to a layout via code.

If you put it as the first child in a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout, it will be rendered first with the possibility of having siblings drawn over it.

Comment: Thanks FunkTheMonk for the help. I am not an expert in android. can you provide me this as a sample.